# Python, OpenOffice: Programmatically Manipulating spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel, openoffice-calc

I have an spreadsheet-based automated report that needs to be created daily, with some charts, aggregating functions (e.g. SUM and AVERAGE) and formatted cells (Dates, percentage, etc.).

I have tried to [write these results directly to an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260678/python-creating-excel-worksheets-with-charts), but Python's [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) and [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.5.2) don'y support charts and functions.

Moreover, trying to open an existing, formatted Excel file and changing some cell's values ended up erasing all charts and functions in the existing file.

Is there a way to write charts and functions to an OpenOffice spreadsheet, or at least change cells in an existing spreadsheet without erasing data? If there is a Pythonic way to do it, I can easily convert the OO file into an Excel file and deliver it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PyUNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python), a Python library to use UNO API.

[Here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=56037#56037) is a Python example to do some manipulations in a Calc document.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. If I'm lucky, I can create the charts and formulae beforehand and simply change the cell's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this: http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/

Open Office.org API's accessible from Python?

Or this?  http://api.openoffice.org/

The OpenOffice.org API Project?

This may be helpful, also: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python

Comment: I've been looking there, but found no concrete explanation on adding charts and formulae.

Answer (score 0):

For creating spreadsheets easily: use [odslib](https://pypi.org/project/odslib/) or for python3: [odslib3](https://pypi.org/project/odslib3/) … even if the project was last updated over six years ago (2013-07-19) it worked straight out of the box and with just one example viewed. Download the package from [the repository](https://bitbucket.org/angry_elf/odslib/src/default/) for the examples.

```
$ pip install odslib
```

and then a sample spreadsheet could be created like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import odslib

doc = odslib.ODS()

def writeRow( doc, row, name, power, rating ):
    doc.content.getCell( 0, row).stringValue( name )
    doc.content.getCell( 1, row).stringValue( power )
    doc.content.getCell( 2, row).floatValue( rating )

# the column names
writeRow( doc, 0, "Name", "Power", "Rating" ) 

# some lines of content
writeRow( doc, 1, "Mr. Incredible", "Strength", 0.8 ) 
writeRow( doc, 2, "Elastigirl", "Elasticity", 0.9 ) 
writeRow( doc, 3, "Frozone", "Ice", 0.7 ) 
writeRow( doc, 4, "Syndrome", "n/a", 0.3 ) 
writeRow( doc, 5, "Jack-Jack", "All", 1.0 ) 

doc.save("supers.ods")
```