# Calling python code from VSTO excel addin

Tags: python, excel, visual-studio-2008, vsto, vba

I am working on an excel2007 plugin in VSTO and am using VB for coding it. One of the item in the plugin is the button, pressing which should give a call to a python program which will add some data to the current worksheet.
I would like to know
1 How can i call the python function from the VBA code
2 pass the active workbook to this code?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`PyXLL`](http://www.pyxll.com) to call a python function from Excel either as a worksheet function or as a macro which you can call from VBA. If you look at the docs for `xl_macro` on the **PyXLL** website you'll find an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also consider integrating Python and Excel via COM as this does have a fair amount of flexibility. See [Driving Excel from Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows) .

For a Python add-in loaded directly in Excel I have also published a simple implementation  at http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/expy/expy.html that is free and with source code.