# How to run excel formulas from python script?

Tags: python, excel, api, xlrd, xlwt

I have an excel spreadsheet with some complicated calculations implemented.

Is there a way I can feed the spreadsheet with input data, run the calculations and get the results from the python script level?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pythonexcels.com/2009/10/python-excel-mini-cookbook/
http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html
[Driving Excel from Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows)

..doable using the win32 python API