# How to close an excel file window using python

Tags: python

I want to check if a particular excel file is open.

If the file is open then save the file and close it.

Using python

Answer (score 1):

There are already a lot of posts on here that answer the same. The following links provide with a good starting guide to use python with excel using win32com,

[Driving Excel from Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows/445961#445961)

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html

http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/