# Transcribe Excel Workbooks via python without spoiling the fancy formatting

Tags: python, excel

I want a generic python-based method to insert some data into a given Excel workbook (a proforma).  The workbook uses formatted sheets - password protected, with limits on which cells can be written to and what can be written into a cell (sometimes via menus of acceptable input).  The data I wish to insert would be acceptable content to the protected cells, if human typed.

I don't want to spoil the fancy formatting, just to emulate the act of typing and then saving.  I need the option of manually adding more information later via Excel.

So far I have looked at xlrd/xlutils.copy/xlwt, but don't see how to preserve the fancy formatting - the protection gets stripped off, the menus disappear, and so on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/), by Mark Hammond.  With that, you control a running instance of Excel via COM (somewhat like programming in VBScript or VBA, except using Python syntax).  See [this earlier Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows) for more details, as well as some other potential options.