# How could I close Excel file using pywinauto

Tags: python, excel, pywinauto

I'm having a problem that I can't excel file.

I was using swapy+pywinauto.
program export excel file with different name (ex. time..) 
I used swapy to close the export excel.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.EXE" \\dde')
xlmain = app.XLMAIN
xlmain.Wait('ready')
xlmain.Close()
app.Kill_()
```

but got error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "D:/23007.py", line 54, in <module>
xlmain.Wait('ready')

WaitUntil(timeout, retry_interval, lambda: self.__check_all_conditions(check_method_names))


File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 308, in WaitUntil
raise err

pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `app.XLMAIN`? Is the title of window similar to `XLMAIN`? Usually the title is `<file name> - Excel` so that pywinauto can handle it so: `xlmain = app["<file name> - Excel"]`.

Obviously `Wait('ready')` raised an exception because the window with title `"XLMAIN"` or similar is not found.

Generally I would recommend using pyWin32 standard module `win32com.client` to work with Excel (through standard COM interface). See the second answer here for example: [Driving Excel from Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks for advising me.. swapy shows XLMAIN so that why I used it.
and problem is...when I export excel file, file name is change every time..(e.g : first time let's say...first.xlsx and..next file name will be second.xlsx)
Do you know how to catch the file name?

Comment: It's possible to use regular expression matching. `xlmain = app.Window_(title_re=".* Excel")`