# Using python to send keys to active Excel Window

Tags: python, excel, keyboard

I need to send keys to excel to refresh formulas.

What are my best options?

I am already using Openpyxl but it does not satisfy all my needs.

Comment: Keyboard keypresses? maybe not python but i've used [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) which is pretty powerful and should be able to do what you want through a small script

Comment: you should give a try to [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) or another excel/python module, without sending keys

Comment: With `pywin32` it's possible to send commands to an excel application: https://stackoverflow.com/a/441786/7306999

Answer (score 1):

If this still helps, you can use from pywin32 (which should be a default package) to use win32com.client.

Sample code:

`import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.sendkeys("^+s")  # saves file`

Use "%" to access alt so you can get hotkeys.

Comment: AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x3181200301120>' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'